# $_POST goes empty after adding a new input type "file"

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm not finding a way to understand and fix this and I've done a lot.

I've got a script, wish is a simple form, that sends a file trough POST. The second file, process the info.

By default, I give to the user a few fields, one of them being a input field of type "file" and there's also, a few "hidden" one's, that gives me values to work with on POST.

I found that, when adding a new input of type "file", the $_POST returns array 0, even $_FILES returns nothing. I have no idea how to fix this, and it works just fine when keeping the default input box of type "file".

```
<form id="formulario" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="projectos_processar.php" method="POST">

    Modo inserir projecto item!<br/><br/>
    <label>Imagem de apresentacao: </label>

    <input id="img_p_child" type="file" name="img_p_child" cols="100" value="" class="validate['required','image']" /><br/>

    <br/>
    <br/>

    <input type="file" id="video" name="video" class="validate['required','video']" cols="100">

    <br/>                       
    <br/>
    <hr>
    Publicar o item ? <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>                       

    Sim <input type="radio" name="published" value="1"><br>
    Nao <input type="radio" name="published" value="0" checked="true"><br>

    <hr>

    <!-- INICIO:: CAMPOS EM MODO HIDDEN -->
    <input type="hidden" value="center" name="crop_X_Y" />
    <input  type="hidden" value="assets/publicidade/FURIOUS01/" name="stringDirPagina" />
    <input  type="hidden" value="128" name="parent_id" />
    <input  type="hidden" value="projectos_item" name="pagina_id"/>
    <input  type="hidden" value="inserir" name="tarefa" />
    <!-- FIM:: CAMPOS EM MODO HIDDEN -->

    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
</form>
```

This only happens when:

```
<input type="file" id="video" name="video" class="validate['required','video']" cols="100">
```

Exists!

`var_dump( $_POST )`, or `$_FILES`, `print_r()`, etc return nothing. I've trieed to create an array on the input of type "files", like `img_p_child[]`, but nothing.

How to solve this ?

Thanks for taking your time!

---

I forgot to mention that, I trieed right now sending a image file in this second input field and works, but not with .FLV file. So I suspect there's a maximum permission, that I need to change on php.ini, if this is the case, I'm sorry! :X

Answer (score 6):

**Taken from [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php):**

> post_max_size affects file upload. To upload large files, this
>   value must be larger than upload_max_filesize. If memory limit is
>   enabled by your configure script, memory_limit also affects file
>   uploading. Generally speaking, memory_limit should be larger than
>   post_max_size. When an integer is used, the value is measured in
>   bytes. Shorthand notation may also be used. If the size of post data
>   is greater than post_max_size, the $_POST and $_FILES superglobals 
>   are empty. This can be tracked in various ways, e.g. by passing the
>   $_GET variable to the script processing the data, i.e. , and then checking if
>   $_GET['processed'] is set.
>
> memory_limit sets the maximum amount of memory in bytes that a script
>   is allowed to allocate. This helps prevent poorly written scripts for
>   eating up all available memory on a server. Note that to have no
>   memory limit, set this directive to -1.

That being said, you need to change some things in your php.ini to allow larger uploads:

```
upload_max_filesize = 10M;
post_max_size = 20M;
memory_limit = 18M;
```

Add the below to your .htaccess file in the you root directory.

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 10M
php_value post_max_size 20M
php_value memory_limit 18M
```

Obviously, these sizes will vary based on your needs. [Here is a nice article](http://blog.paulgu.com/programming/increase-upload-size-in-your-phpini/) on increasing your upload size.