# Getting trouble while uploading a file in PHP

Tags: php

I'm using PHP as server side programming,I'm facing a different type of problem while uploading the images.If the uploading image is having below 8MB is uploading fine but if image size is increases then its not uploading.What might be the problem.I know I've to change in php.ini file,but where I don't know.please help me

Comment: Have you restarted apache too?

Comment: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457173/post-goes-empty-after-adding-a-new-input-type-file/9839985#9839985)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes,you need to change a `upload_max_filesize` value to your desired value in php.ini file.After that you have to restart the server

Answer (score 1):

You need to establish first where your PHP.ini is coming from.  If you create a PHP script with this one line of code in it and access it in your browser, that will tell you:

```
phpinfo();
```

(Mine says: Loaded Configuration File   /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini )

Then edit that file and alter the lines

```
post_max_size = 8M
upload_max_filesize = 8M
```

to something more appropriate.  Then restart Apache.  You may be able to use the .htaccess method in vlzvl's answer, but I'd say probably not.

Answer (score 0):

open you .htaccess and write:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 16M
php_value post_max_size 16M
```